# Calculating drift velocity/number of charge carriers

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

You know current and voltage of a circuit.
how would you calculate number of charge carriers or drift velocity of electron?
through experiments/theoretically

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Comment: tysm anna ... I haven't checked Jacob but thanks i got ans

Comment: i got my answer so how to close this question?

Answer (score -1):

There is the formula
$$I = v_d EnA$$
where $I$ is the current, $v_d$ is the drift velocity, $E$ is the electric field intensity and $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the conductor.

Comment: This answer doesn't say what $n$ is, and incorrectly identifies the $E$ in their formula as electric field, when it should be $e$, the charge on one electron.

Comment: well one eqn and two variables.... nothing can be said.. anyways i got my ans ... anna gave a site